# How do I use python to show data in excel?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to display data from Python in Excel.  Ideally, a pandas dataframe's worth of data would appear in a new, unsaved excel instance.  My search has turned up ways to create excel files, and lots of ways to 'open' an excel file to read data from it, but no way to display it.  My current approach was to create a file and then figure out how to open it, but I consider that approach second-best.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.python-excel.org/). Another way would be to export your data to CSV and import it in Excel.

Comment: Those libraries allow for reading and writing data to excel files, but don't offer a way to open them for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I found you can 'run' files with the OS library.  As long as your computer knows what to do with it, you can create the xlsx file with whatever method and then run it to display:

```
import xlsxwriter
import os

w = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
s=w.add_worksheet("Sheet1")
s.write(1,3,"7")
w.close()

os.startfile(r"C:\Temp\test.xlsx")
```

Still not sure if you can work with an unsaved open instance of excel